# How to convert string to Number in angular 4

Tags: angular, string, numbers

In my angular app, assume I have a string value 00065. I need to convert this to a number and add + 1. i.e; 00065 + 1, which is 00066
Same way if the number is 00120, I should do 00120 +1 which is 00121. 
I don't want the preceeding zeros not be to ignored. As soon as I convert it to number using Number, the preceeding zeros are removed.
how can I acheive this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding zeros in front of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490968/adding-zeros-in-front-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Create method

```
pad(n) { return ("000000" + n).slice(-6); }
```

Call this method in ur model.

> check this link out [@Roberto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30491937/2175572)

here is the example, check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adzgcl

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string using `parseInt`, then if you don't need IE support you can use the `String.prototype.padStart()` method.

For example:

```
function paddedAddOne(value) {
  const nextValue = parseInt(value, 10) + 1;
  return `${nextValue}`.padStart(5, '0')
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to add a polyfill.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt